# Proof: $P(\varnothing)=0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation

To prove(using the three probability axioms):
$$P(\varnothing)=0$$
Is this method correct?

> Let $A$ be an event such that $A=\Omega$. Then $A^\complement=\varnothing$,
>   $$P(A)+P(A^\complement)=1$$
>   $$P(\Omega)+P(\varnothing)=1\tag2$$
>   $$P(\varnothing)=0$$

Please, post any proof that is better/correct.

Comment: Hint: $$P(\emptyset) = P(\emptyset \sqcup \emptyset) = P(\emptyset) + P(\emptyset) = 2P(\emptyset).$$  So...

Comment: @MathLover  No.  $\sqcup$ means disjoint union.  For $A \neq \emptyset$, we do NOT have $A = A \sqcup A.$

Comment: @Dzoooks what is disjoint union? If no set A can have A=A⊔A, how can ∅?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are disjoint if $A \cap B = \emptyset$, that is, they share no common elements.  This is still true when $A=B= \emptyset.$

Comment: @Dzoooks don't use $⊔$ to symbolise a union of disjoint sets, that's not what [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union) means.

Comment: Anyhow, Dzoooks point is that since $\emptyset$ is disjoint from itself (ie $\emptyset\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$), then the *additivity of probability for a union of disjoint sets* means: $$\mathsf P(\emptyset\cup\emptyset)~{=\mathsf P(\emptyset)+\mathsf P(\emptyset)\\=2\mathsf P(\emptyset)}$$

Comment: Just as a secondary hint to drive the point home: How would we establish that $x=2x$ implies that $x=0$? 

It seems from the comments above that we can establish $P(\emptyset)=2P(\emptyset)$ without really any discussion of $\Omega$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp , Dzooks, Mason understood. so, bringing  Ω into discussion is unnecessary because we can simply use the third axiom to prove this.

Comment: @Zaira. Hard to answer that. What axioms are you working with?

Comment: Beware that another solution of $P(\varnothing)+P(\varnothing)=P(\varnothing)$ is $P(\varnothing)=+\infty$, hence one needs an argument (for example, using the axioms of $P$) to get rid of this solution.

Comment: @Mason The three basic axioms of probability https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/pO1x1JNdSxrl8-2vgCYMW43DwsY=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/axioms-56a8fa9a5f9b58b7d0f6e9eb.jpg

Comment: @Did. Thank you. That is a helpful response to my thought a few comments up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that you use is  correct.

You can go for:$$1=P(S)=P(S\cup\varnothing)=P(S)+P(\varnothing)=1+P(\varnothing)$$implying that $P(\varnothing)=0$.

Here the first equality is a consequence of the axioma saying that $P(S)=1$ and the third equality is a consequence of the axioma saying that $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$ is implied by $A\cap B=\varnothing$.

Actually a proof that is better does not exist.